# Группировка сообщений из чата по датам

Tags: php, mysql

**Имеются данные в базе данных**

Данные из таблицы messages
| id | message_text                           | from_user_id | create_user_id  | created_at  |
| :- | :--------------------------------------| :----------- | :-------------- | :---------- |
| 1  | Привет, как дела?                      | 1            | 2               | 1694014642  |
| 2  | Привет, всё отлично!, Как у тебя?      | 2            | 1               | 1694016989  |
| 3  | У меня тоже всё хорошо                 | 1            | 2               | 1694017207  |
| 4  | Ты смотрела новые обновления на сайте? | 1            | 2               | 1694019224  |
| 5  | Да смотрела, очень круто               | 2            | 1               | 1694053168  |              2,            1,              1694053168

```
  /* Загружаем список чатов */
  $getMessages = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `from_user_id` = :from_user_id AND :create_user_id = :create_user_id OR `from_user_id` = :create_user_id AND `create_user_id` = :from_user_id ORDER BY `created_at`");
  $getMessages->execute(array('from_user_id' => $rowUserData['id'], 'user_id' => current_user_id()));

  /* Проверяем есть ли в базе чаты */
  if ($getMessages->rowCount() > 0) {

    while ($rowMessages = $getMessages->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

      echo '<b>' . convertTimestampToDate($rowMessages['created_at']) . '</b>';

      if ($rowMessages['user_id'] == current_user_id()) {

        echo ' <span style="color: green">' . $rowMessages['message_text'] . '</span> ';
        echo convertTimestampToTime($rowMessages['created_at']) . '</br></br>';


      } elseif ($rowMessages['user_id'] == $rowUserData['id']) {

        echo ' <span style="color: grey">' . $rowMessages['message_text'] . '</span> ';
        echo convertTimestampToTime($rowMessages['created_at']) . '</br></br>';
      }
    }
  } else {
    echo 'У вас нет сообщений с данным пользователем';
  }
```

*Написанный мной код выводит данные из базы данных следующим образом:*
**Среда, 06 сентябрь** Привет, как дела? 18:37
**Среда, 06 сентябрь** Привет, всё отлично!, Как у тебя? 19:16
**Среда, 06 сентябрь** У меня тоже всё хорошо 19:20
**Вчера** Ты смотрела новые обновления на сайте? 05:19
**Сегодня** Да смотрела, очень круто 20:16

*Желаемый результат:*
**Среда, 06 сентябрь**
Привет, как дела? 18:37
Привет, всё отлично!, Как у тебя? 19:16
У меня тоже всё хорошо 19:20
**Вчера**
Ты смотрела новые обновления на сайте? 05:19
**Сегодня**
Да смотрела, очень круто 20:16

Сколько не ломай голову ничего на ум не приходит, поиски тоже безуспешны

Comment: Разумеется, поиски будут безуспешны, потому что это называется **группировка**, а не "сортировка"

Answer (score 0):

Нашел всё таки решение, надеюсь и другим тоже понадобится

````
/* Загружаем список чатов */
  $getMessages = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `from_user_id` = :from_user_id AND :create_user_id = :create_user_id OR `from_user_id` = :create_user_id AND `create_user_id` = :from_user_id ORDER BY `created_at`");
  $getMessages->execute(array('from_user_id' => $rowUserData['id'], 'user_id' => current_user_id()));

  /* Проверяем есть ли в базе чаты */
  if ($getMessages->rowCount() > 0) {
    while ($rowMessages = $getMessages->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

      if ($chatDate != convertTimestampToDate($rowMessages['created_at'])) {
        $chatDate = convertTimestampToDate($rowMessages['created_at']);
        echo '<h4>' . convertTimestampToDate($rowMessages['created_at']) . '</h4>';
      }
    
      echo '<b>' . convertTimestampToDate($rowMessages['created_at']) . '</b>';

      if ($rowMessages['user_id'] == current_user_id()) {

        echo ' <span style="color: green">' . $rowMessages['message_text'] . '</span> ';
        echo convertTimestampToTime($rowMessages['created_at']) . '</br></br>';


      } elseif ($rowMessages['user_id'] == $rowUserData['id']) {

        echo ' <span style="color: grey">' . $rowMessages['message_text'] . '</span> ';
        echo convertTimestampToTime($rowMessages['created_at']) . '</br></br>';
      }
    }
  } else {
    echo 'У вас нет сообщений с данным пользователем';
  }```
````